# How to use a for loop in a jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to use  a for loop in a jquery for editing and storing multiple edited values in a hidden input field in an MVC4 application

This is my Jquery

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('p').click(function () {
            var textbox = $('<input id="Text1" type="text"  name="Name" />')
            var oldText = $(this).text();
            $(this).replaceWith(textbox);
            textbox.blur(function () {
                var newValue = $(this).val();
                var listItems = $('.listItem');
                listItems.each(function () {
                    $(this).replaceWith(
                    $('<p/>', { text: newValue })
                    .after(
                       $('<input />', { type: 'hidden', name: 'Name', value: newValue })
                    )
                );
                });
                });

              textbox.val(oldText);
        });
    });  


</script>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is, what does the for loop do? What fields is it looping over? Why are we using a loop?

Comment: i have a model class were i assigned name,address,pincode which i display in my view when edited these multiple fields using that jquery i want to store all the edited fields on that page and show on next  View in my MVC4 application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a model:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            Name = "test1",
            Address = "add1"
        };
        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(User user)
    {
        return Content(
            string.Format(
                "name: {0}, address: {1}", 
                user.Name, 
                user.Address
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model User

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul class="editor">
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, Model.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address, Model.Address)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Now you could use the following javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.editor input').blur(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('li').find('label').html($(this).val()).show();
    });

    $('.editor label').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('li').find('input').show();
    });
});
```

and finally in order to initially hide the input fields you could define the `.editor` CSS rule that I have applied to the `<ul>` element:

```
.editor input {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin i assigned an id to both the properties for name i gave 1 and Address 2 ,So when i edit Name i want to display id of Name and similar thing Address but i am unable to pass id to the controller class in the above example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop any collection in jquery use `each()`. Why `for` ?

```
 $.each(collectionarray, function( index, value ) {
 // your code
 });
```

Comment: I tried that its not working i am unable to store multiple edited field values

Comment: For example i assigned Name=Danny Addres=Chicago i want to edit these two fields in my page and pass both edited values to next Viwe